# Android - Changing ViewElements from Network Thread (or how else)

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I have implemented a socket connection between two Android phones.
The local phone needs to update some view elements since I want to show the position on a self made map.

The Android programming guideline does not approve to change View elements from outside my activity.
That means I can not call a methode like this:

```
mainActivity.updateView(positionX);
```

because I would run it in the network thread.
So what is the official way of doing it? I know there is *runOnUIThread* but that looks like a quickfix on first sight.

Or should I need an AsyncTask? But the API says that one is not practicable for longer tasks and I need the Thread to run in background all the time (and get updates very often).

So isn't it a big thing to create a new Handler/AsyncTask to simply set a small icon somewhere else in the MainActivity? After all, I assume maybe even 50 changes per second.

Hopefully someone here knows the right way to do this.
 Thanks!

P.S. Okay, so please allow me to ask, if there is at least an option to overwrite something like the onDraw Method. After all, that sounds like the best idea since creating always new threads seems a slight overkill. So I would like to tell the "redraw()" method to get the information I stored (synchronized) in the Network Thread. So I wouldn't need any further threads.
Does anyone know something about that? Thank you!

Comment: runonuithread is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Handlers!
Handlers are a great way to do what you want. You should implement a handler in your Activity like this:

```
private class NetworkHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle data = msg.getData();
        int message = data.getInt("message");
        switch (message) {


        case Network.NET_GAME_FINISHED: UPDATE YOUR UI
                                                    break;
                    case ...
                    }
             }
}
```

And when you receive something from the network, you just send a message to that handler.

Look at [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) tutorial.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reference to the activity, you can run code on the UI thread as follows:

```
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    activity.runOnUiThread (new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //UI thread code here
                            }
                        });
```

Personally, I would use an AsyncTask because the class does a whole lot more to optimize the process of creating a new thread and managing its lifecycle.  In an AsyncTask you can simply put your UI code in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: But isn't it very "expensive" if I get an update perhaps 50 times per second to always start a new thread there just to change a tiny detail and than destroy it again? I was trying to avoid this - or is there no chance for that?

Comment: That is definitely a valid concern.  I would try implementing it with an AsyncTask since it is so simple, and if you have performance concerns then consider profiling that implementation - it should be very easy to do.  Keep in mind that AsyncTasks have a lot of optimizations for threads and pooling (for example, it uses small pools of threads that get reused instead of constantly creating and destroying threads).  Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, sounds like I'm paying some price for keeping two players uptodate. So is that how all those network MMORPG & Co. programs do it? Running a background Thread that creates a AsyncTask 50 times a second? Thanks anyway. :-(

Comment: No game is making 50 individual network calls during each game logic update.  Usually game logic and graphics get updated at 30-60fps, and depending on the game requirements, model updates from the server may come at much slower intervals.  Games that require near real time updates would almost certainly be written using the NDK, or a game framework that wraps around the NDK like libgdx: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/ Network communication would probably be handled by something like a socket in Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: Hm, okay, so the clou is to put all updates together into "one packet" and send them maybe once or twice per second? But than creating a new AsyncTask or Handler (not sure about this yet) to update the Activity.
Isn't there anything like onDraw which I could directly override in the View to simply get the view-data every time the element is drawn?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making your activity register to receive an intent and your code running on the network thread can broadcast the intent.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a service for handling your sockets (since its a long running task which can run in the background) and implementing the communication between your UI and the service using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and messages (Or possibly using an [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) interface to the service and another towards your UI, but that would be more complicated)?